# Why does audioConext fail on UC Mobile

Tags: html, getusermedia, uc-browser

We have a requirement to make a web app that works on UC mobile for Android (as well as chrome but we have that working). We need to record audio so we can send it back to our web server.

However even though getUserMedia is supposed to work on UC mobile, what works on Chrome doesn't work on it.
I have followed these instructions here for example:

http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio/

Note - to get it to work at all, I have to specify video even though I don't need it:

```
var mediaConstraints = {  audio: true,   video: {  width: 320,    height: 460    }    };
getUserMedia(mediaConstraints) ...
```

Just asking for audio didn't work for me (got getUserMedia error)

```
var mediaConstraints = {audio: true};
```

The big problem I had was that the audioContext() call doesn't work (called in the getUserMedia success function) e.g.

```
context = new audioContext();
```

It works for chrome, but UC mobile just stops here with no error. I need example code that successfully records uncorrupted audio using UC mobile browser on Android.

Comment: Don't care either way whether video is also recorded. External libraries are OK, even paid ones if they work.